# Mac Terminal Multiple Commands Single Line in Lua

Tags: macos, lua

I have a Win Command prompt with 3 command on one line in Lua script and need the equivalent for Mac:

```
([[cmd.exe /C " cd ]] .. script_path .. [[sonic/win32/ & set VAMP_PATH=]] .. script_path .. [[sonic/win32/vamp; ]].. script_path .. [[ & "sonic-annotator.exe" -d vamp:nnls-chroma:chordino:simplechord -w csv "]].. filename ..[["]],0)
```

There are 3 commands in the one line "&". The Mac is sonic/mac64/sonic-annotator

1. it opens the command prompt and changes directory to /sonic/win32/
   &
2. then sets the Vamp plugin path for sonic-annotator to /sonic/win32/vamp
   &
3. then apply the effect to the source wav file "filename" that creates a csv file with chord or tempo info that's imported into Reaper DAW.

This is info to set VAMP folder for Win/Lin/Mac

```
You need to set the VAMP_PATH environment variable so as to point to the directory with the plugins in it. How you do this depends on the platform.

Linux and macOS using bash in a terminal window:

$ export VAMP_PATH=/path/to/plugin/directory
$ sonic-annotator -l

(or whatever sonic-annotator options you want)

Windows using Command Prompt:

> set VAMP_PATH=/path/to/plugin/directory
> sonic-annotator -l

Windows using PowerShell:

> $env:VAMP_PATH = "/path/to/plugin/directory"
> & sonic-annotator -l

Note that in all cases, setting the path to "." will make Sonic Annotator read plugins from the current working directory at the time you run it. If you have plugins + sonic-annotator binary in the same directory, you can cd to that directory and run (in bash) the one-liner

$ VAMP_PATH=. ./sonic-annotator -l
```

Comment: `local command = 'export VAMP_PATH="'..script_path..'vamp"; cd "'..script_path..'"; ./sonic-annotator -d vamp:nnls-chroma:chordino:simplechord -w csv "'..filename..'"'`

Comment: That worked thanks.